# Azure cognitive search stop working with message "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, azure, search, azure-cognitive-search

My Azure search service was working perfectly until two weeks ago when I had an error message saying "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". I tried to update the nuget packges to use the latest versions, I refreshed the tokens but nothing works. Any help please, my site is completely down because of this.

Comment: are you using free tier?

Comment: Yes I'm using free tier and it has been working fine for more than 4 years

Comment: there's a new behavior for free tier. If it won't receive requests in 90 days, it will delete your resource. That may be the problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the new thing regarding the free tier but my API is get queries everyday so it shouldn't be that problem

Comment: The service is still up and running, azure support checked the status and told me that there is nothing wrong but I still can't search

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see whether these issues are relating to SSL handshake negotiation? If your client isn't using TLS 1.2, that's the first place I would suggest looking.

Comment: Shouldn't the SDK use the appropriate SSL handshake? If not how can I specify it manually please?